# AVD doesn't boot. Stuck on "Android" logo

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device, boot

My virtual machine of a Nexus 5 with Google API 21 System image x86 does not boot up. This is the logcat output from the machine. It is a loop, so I post only a part of it.

This is the most relevant part, in my honest opinion. I think that is the crash of something. It happens on KitKat image and Lollipop image.

```
D/dalvikvm( 1868): GC_CONCURRENT freed 313K, 10% free 8273K/9144K, paused 22ms+37ms, total 248ms
D/dalvikvm( 1868): GC_CONCURRENT freed 869K, 10% free 8638K/9576K, paused 31ms+34ms, total 282ms
D/dalvikvm( 1868): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 10% free 8640K/9576K, paused 96ms, total 96ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1868): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.053MB for 577450-byte allocation
F/libc    ( 1868): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xbd49815c (code=1), thread 1868 (system_server)
I/DEBUG   (  923): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  923): Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/999428:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  923): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  923): pid: 1868, tid: 1868, name: system_server  >>> system_server <<<
I/DEBUG   (  923): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr bd49815c
I/DEBUG   (  923):     eax e2d739aa  ebx 0000003f  ecx 00000035  edx 0000000a
I/DEBUG   (  923):     esi bd498060  edi b9690470
I/DEBUG   (  923):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   (  923):     eip b644e900  ebp a0410020  esp bfcb9840  flags 00200286
I/DEBUG   (  923): 
I/DEBUG   (  923): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  923):     #00  pc 0003b900  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (bn_mul_mont+944)
I/DEBUG   (  923): 
I/DEBUG   (  923): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9800  bfcba36c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9804  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9808  bfcb98a8  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb980c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9810  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9814  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9818  b4e119fc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb981c  00000075  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9820  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9824  bfcb9f4c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9828  00000010  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb982c  b766825b  /system/lib/libc.so (__sfvwrite+411)
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9830  bfcba027  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9834  b4e11ad0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9838  00000010  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb983c  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  923):     #00  bfcb9840  bfcb9e8c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9844  b9690470  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9848  b968ff10  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb984c  b969024c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9850  b9690020  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9854  2cb9d869  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9858  bfcba02c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb985c  b9690250  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9860  8511d85f  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9864  432bf275  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9868  a3cd7bc4  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb986c  5ae2ef9c  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9870  a951d3c8  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so (gpu::gles2::GLES2Implementation::GetBooleanv(unsigned int, unsigned char*)+120)
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9874  ee0f795a  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb9878  f899d6f3  
I/DEBUG   (  923):          bfcb987c  3c3cf1aa  
I/DEBUG   (  923): 
I/DEBUG   (  923): memory map around fault addr bd49815c:
I/DEBUG   (  923):     b97d1000-b97f2000 rw- [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  923):     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   (  923):     bfc9c000-bfcbd000 rw- [stack]
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'telephony.registry' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'scheduling_policy' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'sensorservice' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'appops' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'display' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'power' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'batterystats' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'usagestats' died
E/installd(  929): eof
E/installd(  929): failed to read size
I/installd(  929): closing connection
D/Zygote  ( 1595): Process 1868 terminated by signal (11)
I/Zygote  ( 1595): Exit zygote because system server (1868) has terminated
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager(  919): service 'media.audio_policy' died
I/Netd    ( 1896): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController( 1896): Warning (dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
I/mediaserver( 1898): ServiceManager: 0xb8ee7d40
I/AudioFlinger( 1898): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/CameraService( 1898): CameraService started (pid=1898)
D/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient( 1898): Emulated camera list: 
D/EmulatedCamera_FakeCamera( 1898): Initialize: Fake camera is facing back
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with auto, 1.000000, 1.000000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with incandescent, 1.380000, 0.600000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with daylight, 1.090000, 0.920000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with twilight, 0.920000, 1.220000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): setWhiteBalanceMode with white balance auto
D/EmulatedCamera_FakeCamera( 1898): Initialize: Fake camera is facing front
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with auto, 1.000000, 1.000000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with incandescent, 1.380000, 0.600000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with daylight, 1.090000, 0.920000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with twilight, 0.920000, 1.220000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device( 1898): setWhiteBalanceMode with white balance auto
I/CameraService( 1898): Loaded "Emulated Camera Module" camera module
I/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1898): loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
D/AndroidRuntime( 1897): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 1897): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
W/linker  ( 1897): libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
I/AudioFlinger( 1898): loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from Generic audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
I/AudioFlinger( 1898): HAL output buffer size 1024 frames, normal mix buffer size 1024 frames
I/AudioMixer( 1898): found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
I/AudioFlinger( 1898): Using module 1 has the primary audio interface
I/AudioFlinger( 1898): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb5fc0010 ready to run
W/AudioFlinger( 1898): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
W/AudioFlinger( 1898): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
```

Otherwise, this is the complete log:

http://pastebin.com/Ci7Ah97W

Host system:

```
Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite

Android Studio 1.0.1

Build #AI-135.1641136, built on December 11, 2014

JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716 x86_64

JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Apple Inc.
```

The specs of the machise are:

```
Name: Nexus_5_API_21

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /Users/matteo/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21.avd

Target: Google APIs (API level 21)

Skin: nexus_5

SD Card: /Users/matteo/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21.avd/sdcard.img

Snapshot: no

hw.lcd.density: 480

hw.dPad: no

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera.back: emulated

disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

runtime.network.latency: none

skin.dynamic: no

hw.keyboard: yes

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88

hw.ramSize: 1572864

tag.id: google_apis

tag.display: Google APIs

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.device.name: Nexus 5

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.battery: yes

AvdId: Nexus_5_API_21

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.gps: yes

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 21

snapshot.present: no

vm.heapSize: 64

runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

I tried to change the amount of RAM (from 512 to 3 GB but my physical RAM is 4GB), host GPU on/off, enabling/disabling snapshot but nothing changes. The output are always the same.

Comment: You should add the relevant information to your question. Do not put information on sites like Pastebin and then ask folks to go offsite. You can update your question by clicking *Edit*.

Comment: The log is bigger than the permitted size (30000 lines, log are 100000+ lines). I'll add the part, in my opinion, most relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It helped me to remove old HAX and install new one updated.